# Get x and y labels for tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have plotted a scatter diagram with `pgfplots`:

[image]

With this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=10.5, xmin=0, xmax=10.5,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,font=\scriptsize,scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}] 
            \addplot[scatter,only marks] coordinates {%
(0.5,1) (1,2) (2,2) (3,3) (4,3) (5,5) (6,4) (6,6) (7,8) (8,7) (9,9) (10,9)
                };              
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

How do I get the `$x$` and `$y$` to be on the right side of the `x`-axis and the top of the `y`-axis respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xlabel style` and `ylabel style` like

```
xlabel style={at={(1,0)},right},
ylabel style={at={(0,1)},above,rotate=-90},
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=10.5, xmin=0, xmax=10.5,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,font=\scriptsize,scatter/use mapped color={draw=black},xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={at={(1,0)},right},
  ylabel style={at={(0,1)},above,rotate=-90},
]
            \addplot[scatter,only marks] coordinates {%
(0.5,1) (1,2) (2,2) (3,3) (4,3) (5,5) (6,4) (6,6) (7,8) (8,7) (9,9) (10,9)
                };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]